# Vscode python debbuger arguments get mixed with ptvsd_launcher

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging python in Vscode, I did set the launch.json for passing arguments to the script with the `"args"` field.

```
{
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            //"src\\vhdl\\counter-e.vhd",
            //"src\\vhdl\\counter-rtl-a.vhd"
            "--help"
        ],
},
```

When I pass specific args, works ok, but I wanted to check the args `-h` or `-v` (test them in my python script) and the debugger gets confused and shows the help for `ptvsd_launcher.py`, and I get the output of that script instead of mine, which does not get executed:

```
cd c:\Users\jreyesga\Documents\features && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && python c:\Users\jreyesga\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py --client --host localhost --port 51724 C:\Users\jreyesga\Documents\features\main.py --help "
usage: c:\Users\jreyesga\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.10.1\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py
       [-h] [--nodebug] [--client] --host HOST --port PORT [--multiprocess]
       [-m MODULE] [-c CODE] [--pid PID] [--single-session] [--wait] [-V]
       [filename]

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --nodebug
  --client
  --host HOST
  --port PORT
  --multiprocess
  -m MODULE
  -c CODE
  --pid PID
  --single-session
  --wait
  -V, --version     show program's version number and exit
```

How could this behavior be escaped?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd .